# Is it possible to change all JQuery UI Dialog buttons (Yes/No/Cancel) titles?

Tags: jquery, localization, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to change the title of every Yes, No and Cancel button, or do I have to do this for every dialog individually?

More detail as requested:

In a typical JQuery dialog, the dialog buttons are defined like this:

```
buttons: {
   Yes: function () {
   },
   No: function () {
   }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to change the "Yes", "No" and "Cancel" button text, without altering every dialog.

So if e.g. the dialog is defined as above the "Yes" button should automatically have the correct localized title.

Comment: please give some more detail of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You have nearly 4k reputation, yet still only provide a question with absolutely no detail. Any more information, like what plugin you're using, source code etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume we are talking about jQuery UI's dialog.  I'd suggest writing a plugin that wraps the dialog plugin and passes all options through except for the title's of the Yes, No, or Cancel buttons.  These you could set within your wrapper plugin.

This is fairly straight forward to do.  Here's one way to get started:

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.myDialog = function( options ) {  

        return this.each(function() {

    var settings = $.extend( {
          'buttons'         : buttons: [
        {
            text: "My Yes",
            click: options.myOkCallback
        },
        {
            text: "My Cancel",
            click: options.myCancelCallback
        },
        {
            text: "My No",
            click: options.myNoCallback
        }
    ]

    }, options);

    $(this).dialog(settings);

});

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: You are right. The question is about the jQuery UI dialog. I updated the question's title. Thank you for your suggestion, if there is no easier way, I will probably use your solution.

Comment: just added a fairly simple example, in case you decide to write a wrapper

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to modify the original dialog instead of using a different name? Otherwise I will have to replace all the 'dialog's in the whole project.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but, you could assign the old dialog function to another function `$.fn.oldDialog = $.fn.dialog;` use `$(this).oldDialog(settings)` in your plugin and name your plugin $.fn.dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":button[value=Yes]").val("Evet");
```

it will translate all buttons that has value "Yes" to Tukish yes "Evet".
You can find JSFiddle [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mZvnq/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The solution doesn't work (yet) most likely because the dialog buttons are sometimes defined *after* the translation lines are executed.